# Pocketsphinx en español?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero un programa que reconozca ciertas palabras. Tengo el siguiente codigo que funciona bien usando la api de google recognize_google y ademas, la puedo configurar en español facilmente. Pero necesito usar recognize_sphinx porque es gratuita y funciona offline.

El tema es que no me reconoce las palabras en ingles que le digo y no entiendo como poder configurarle el diccionario en español que se puede descargar aca: 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Spanish/

Porque no me reconoce lo que digo en ingles y la api de google si? Se supone que es bueno pocketsphinx.
Que tengo que agregar al codigo para que funcione con español?

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)   
    while True:
         audio = r.listen(source)
         # recognize speech using Sphinx
         try:
             print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
          except sr.UnknownValueError:
              print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
          except sr.RequestError as e:
             print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Descargate esos archivos de esa url (todos).

2) Crea un archivo al lado de ellos llamado prueba.py con el siguiente codigo:

```js
import os
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path

model_path = get_model_path()

speech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'es'),
    lm=os.path.join(model_path, 'es-20k.lm.gz'),
    dic=os.path.join(model_path, 'es.dict')
)

for phrase in speech:
    print(phrase)
```

3) Descomprime cmusphinx-es-XX.tar.gz entras y copia lo que esta dentro de model_parameters que es la carpeta voxforge_es_sphinx.cd_ptm_4000.

4) entra en /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx/model y pega esa carpeta alli, cambiale el nombre por "es", pega tambien alli mismo los archivos es-20k.lm.gz y es.dict.

5) Listo ejecuta en la terminal con "python prueba.py" y comienza a hablar.

Nota: no olvides instalar las dependencias que están publicadas en la pagina oficial.

Comment: Yo tuve que descomprimir el archivo **es-20k.lm.gz**, y actualizar la línea del parámetro lm, dejándola así: lm=os.path.join(model_path, 'es-20k.lm'). Antes de ese cambio, la consola de python me mostraba el error: **RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1**